# Specifying entitlements in Pod Spec Test's App Host with Cocoapods

Tags: cocoapods

I have a pod which utilizes the iOS Keychain and have written tests around this functionality. I've specified that I need an app host by specifying `requires_app_host = true` on my test spec. The Keychain functionality fails to work with the following error:

```
OSStatus error:[-34018] Internal error when a required entitlement isn't present, client has neither application-identifier nor keychain-access-groups entitlements.
```

It looks like the app may need entitlements with one of `application-identifier` or `keychain-access-groups` (shared keychain) set. Is there any way to add this to the app host target?

Answer (score 3):

You can create your custom app_spec and specify it as app_host for test. After that, you can configure entitlements for this target

For example:

```
  s.test_spec 'Tests' do |t|
    t.source_files = [
      'MyLibrary/Tests/*.swift',
    ]
    
    t.requires_app_host = true
    t.app_host_name = 'MyLibrary/Example'
    t.dependency 'MyLibrary/Example'    
  end

  s.app_spec 'Example' do |app_spec|
      app_spec.source_files = 'Example/*.swift'
      app_spec.xcconfig = {
          'CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS' => 'MyLibrary/Extension.entitlements'
      }
  end
```